# display transition (multiple transition)

Tags: css, transition, display

I have following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    text text text
</div>

<img id="img1" src="img1.png" />
<img id="img2" src="img2.png" />
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0vh;
    transition: margin-top 1s ease-in 0.1s, display 0.1s linear 5s ;
}
```

JS:

```
$("img#img1").on('click', function () {
    $("#container").css('margin-top', '50vh');
    $("#container").css('display', 'none');
});

$("img#img2").on('click', function () {
    $("#container").css('margin-top', '0vh');
    $("#container").css('display', 'block');
});
```

Looking on CSS file, my intention is:

- margin-top property, change after 0.1 second, for 1 second
- display property, change after 5 second, for 0.1s

But it doesn't work. The display property is changed immediately after click on image.

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

To add a delay in JavaScript, you can use the `setTimeout` function.

To add a five-second delay in your code, you would do the following:

```
$("img#img1").on('click', function () {
    $("#container").css('margin-top', '50vh');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#container").css('display', 'none');
    }, 5000);
});

$("img#img2").on('click', function () {
    $("#container").css('margin-top', '0vh');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#container").css('display', 'block');
    }, 5000);
});
```

The 5000 in this code is 5 seconds represented in millseconds. Hopefully the rest is self-explanatory - a function is specified which is executed after the set length of time.

Not quite sure what you mean about changing `display` for 0.1s though. An element is either displayed or it isn't - there is no in-between. If want something to fade, change its opacity instead. You probably ought to remove "`, display 0.1s linear 5s`" from your CSS too.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain why. No JavaScript wasn't specified as a requirement and CSS transitions don't work on `display`. I did mention that the opacity can be changed if that's the desired effect, but that alone won't hide the element from the document without reserving space like `display` does. Of course, you could do a mixture of things such as fading an element and then setting `display` to `none` and vice-versa.